# Will I lose Netflix on my Nexus One if I use a custom ROM?

Tags: nexus-one, custom-roms, netflix

I'm running stock 2.3.4 on my N1. And use Netflix all the time. If I were to load a different ROM like Cyanogen there isn't any reason I would lose the ability to use Netflix would I?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I use netflix on my Samsung Galaxy S Vibrant with CyanogenMod 7 and it works just fine. Now, that doesn't mean in the future, nextflix couldn't update their app to not support these devices/ROM but it does work now.

Comment: How are you running Netflix on a Galaxy S? I thought they weren't supported...

Comment: AFAIK netflix removed the "check" for unsupported devices from their last update. I don't know if there is something additional in CyanogenMOD for the vibrant that allows it too or not. but it works.

Comment: Interesting. Some quick searching seems to indicate that it only works on 2.3 ROMs on the Vibrant (possibly other SGS phones). Others seem to indicate there's not check at all now, but some devices still refuse to stream (and claim "not supported"). Don't know what to make of that, really.

Comment: Yes, i remember reading that it must be a 2.3 ROM, I have CM7 nightly which is 2.3